# AuthorizationManager check failed in Visual Studio Online running powershell script

Tags: powershell, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm trying to run a powershell script that access the VSTS API and it works ok if I run it in PowerShell ISE.
But I need to add the script as a task in the release process in VSTS and I'm getting a security error. The error I got is:

> **AuthorizationManager check failed.
>   CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
>   FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess**

The script just get the work items from an specific build and then saves those work items to a file like follows

```
function Invoke-ServiceGetBuilds($headers)
{
    Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://myaccount.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/My-Software/_apis/build/builds?api-version=2.0"&"minFinishTime=2016-12-01"&"buildNumber=master_*"&"resultFilter=succeeded -headers $headers -Method Get
    return $result
}

$username = "usr"
$password = "pass*"
$filePath = "file.html"
$releaseName = ""

$basicAuth = ("{0}:{1}" -f $username, $password)
$basicAuth = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($basicAuth);
$basicAuth = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($basicAuth)
$headers = @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $basicAuth)}

$returnedBuilds = Invoke-ServiceGetBuilds $headers

#...create the object and the array of workitems HTML
ConvertTo-Html -body "<h2>Build Information and WI</h2> $workItemsHtml" -Title "Release Report" | Out-File $filePath
```

The script works well if I run it from PowerShell ISE but fails in VSTS
Any idea on how to fix this issue

Comment: You should post the script code if it is small enough (or a minimal verifiable example that illustrates your problem) and the exact set of actions you attempt.

Comment: Please publish the script and what is the error you are getting if any ...